# Setting up a static 0.46 based etcd cluster (no discovery URL)

Tags: coreos

I'm having some trouble setting up etcd cluster without using a discovery URL running on CoreOS.

The configuration is via cloud-init.
The 3 servers in the cluster are listed under peers below.  Each has a different IP and has addr and peer-addr set statically.

For example, the first server is contains:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  etcd:
      addr: 192.168.0.50:4001
      peer-addr: 192.168.0.50:7001
      peers: 192.168.0.50:7001,192.168.0.51:7001,192.168.0.52:7001
```

What I'm seeing in journalctl is:

> WARNING | fail syncing cluster([http://192.168.0.50:7001
>   http://127.0.0.1:7001])

And errors like these:

> locksmithd[12262]: etcd.service is active locksmithd[12262]: Error
>   initializing etcd client: 402: Standby Internal Error (

I assume because etcd isn't working correctly.

Unfortunately, the CoreOS website does not detail a static setup of CoreOS & etcd in practice.

Once that is working, what would my cloud-config look like for a proxied etcd instance?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe you only need specify the *other* peers? I note your error message is that failed to sync with *itself*. Of course, that means a different cloud-config for each instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using static discovery, etcd 0.4.x selects the initial leader of the cluster as the node that was started without a `--peer` list. You'll need to omit the `peers:` section of one of your cloud-configs.

etcd 2.0.0 will allow you to bootstrap the cluster in the way your attempting now, which is providing a static list to all members and bring the cluster up that way. Check out the static clustering docs: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/clustering.md#static

etcd 2.0.0 isn't shipping in a CoreOS image/channel, but look for it soon!

Comment: Thanks.  I had seen the etcd 2 documentation but it didn't match version 1.  I wonder if cloud-config files for version 0.4x going to be compatible with etcd 2.x?

Comment: I finally got it to work by stopping the etcd service on all the nodes, clearing out /var/lib/etcd.  Fixing the cloud-config by removing peers from one of them and rebooting them.

Comment: One last question, do I need to put my own machine in the peers list?  e.g. for the example provided, if it was not the initial leader would it need to have it's own 192.168.0.50 IP in the peers list?

Comment: Once the cluster is started, do I add a peers setting to /usr/share/oem/cloud-init.yml on the machine that previously didn't have a peers setting and reboot?

Just asking, because I rebooted some nodes to check if they came up OK and it was a bit hit and miss.  At one point it went completely broken again.